# При запуске кода выдает следующее "The Zen of Python, by Tim Peters"

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code, pep

При запуске кода у меня выходит эта надпись, не могу понять что делать

The Zen of Python, by Tim Peters

Beautiful is better than ugly.
Explicit is better than implicit.
Simple is better than complex.
Complex is better than complicated.
Flat is better than nested.
Sparse is better than dense.
Readability counts.
Special cases aren't special enough to break the rules.
Although practicality beats purity.
Errors should never pass silently.
Unless explicitly silenced.
In the face of ambiguity, refuse the temptation to guess.
There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it.
Although that way may not be obvious at first unless you're Dutch.
Now is better than never.
Although never is often better than *right* now.
If the implementation is hard to explain, it's a bad idea.
If the implementation is easy to explain, it may be a good idea.
Namespaces are one honking great idea -- let's do more of those!

И не выдает ошибку, пока я не отключаю
Что здесь не так, помогите пожалуйста?

Comment: код то предоставьте, у вас где то `import this` наверняка

Comment: Даа, я это исправил, спасибо большое.
Вопрос не актуален

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я уверен, что в коде подключается библиотека `this` ¯\_(ツ)_/¯